# Alternate university course allocation mechanisms

Tags: administration, policy

When it comes to course enrollment/registration in a limited-enrollment course, most institutions use a sequential system where students pick their course schedules sequentially (often ordered by seniority, then first-come-first-served or randomly within groups with the same seniority). Some institutions, particularly business schools, use "bidding mechanisms," where students bid (in bidding points, not real money) on the opportunity to take over-demanded courses.

These have their advantages and disadvantages, but it seems like there ought to be other ways to handle course allocation. For example, a university might use a system like a sports draft, in which people pick just one course at a time.  **Are such draft systems actually used and are there other interesting non-standard ways of handling registration for restricted-enrollment graduate or undergraduate courses?**

*A clarification: By sequential mechanisms, I mean mechanisms in which students one-by-one select their full course schedule for the upcoming term. Obviously some systems allow a group of students to register within a given window. I still count this as sequential as it is processed sequentially: the order within that window is determined by the order in which the students in that registration window submit their requests. In economics and mechanism design, this is typically referred to as a sequential dictatorship (or a serial dictatorship, which is slightly different only in that the order is predetermined and not dependent on previous selections).*

Comment: Where I studied, it was first come first served, and the date you could register depended on your surname.

Comment: This question reads a bit like a shopping question (it is looking for any number of examples), but one might hope it can be changed to be more suitable. For instance, you could ask whether any university uses the described system where "people pick just one course at a time" (thus, describing one or more examples to prove that yes, there are such universities with that particular system, is a valid and acceptable answer). Alternatively, you might ask for a solution to avoid the system to mention. The problem with the current question is the request for an open-ended "list of examples".

Comment: Also, could you clarify what you mean by "sequentially", please? Does it mean that essentially, all courses can be registered at a time, so a student takes half an hour to one-by-one (i.e. sequentially) click the desired courses into their schedule? Or does it mean a certain sequence in which courses need to be registered is prescribed, so you first have to pick a course of type A, and then a course of type B? Or something else?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Is it to be avoided in this community to have a question structured as it is currently? It's a fairly common format on other SE sites. On math and economics, I see it used for literature requests. On cooking, it is used to solicit multiple techniques or various ingredients or substitutes. On stackoverflow and puzzling sometimes answers are given in multiple languages. Obviously it makes it somewhat arbitrary to accept a single answer, but it seems fairly prevalent nonetheless.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thank you for pointing out the ambiguity. Could you confirm that my edit to the question sufficiently clarifies what I mean by a sequential mechanism?

Comment: @Shane: Questions that do not yield one clear "canonical" answer seem to be generally discouraged on most SE sites, due to the format of the sites. On StackOverflow, out of equivalent answers, the one that explains things best, provides most references, or covers the most general case is usually chosen to get accepted. Other answers might be equally valid and maybe not even fully equivalent, as they might cover an edge case. Still, that is not comparable to asking for a mere enumeration of examples. A question like "What does QuickSort look like in a language of your choice?" or "Which ...

Comment: ... are examples of algorithms that can be written in Java?" would be considered just as off-topic there.

Comment: @Shane: As for your clarification; indeed, that makes things clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Your point is well taken. Upon reflection, I feel that it would be best answered in a community wiki, which I've started. If others (or you) vote to close this because you feel it is a "shopping list" question, I certainly understand that logic. But I do think it is a question that is answerable in this format and might be useful to others.

Comment: I have edited to make it non-list-centric and focusing instead on the mechanisms, and voted to reopen.

Comment: @jakebeal Thank you. I appreciate the edit and agree that it gives the question more focus.

Comment: I think the edit actually makes it more "list-y." Now it sounds like you want a list of universities (including those using methods that have already been described in an answer), which is *much* broader than a list of methods. I wouldn't have voted to close before but I probably would now. (I say this as a user, it's not an Official Moderator Opinion or anything.)

Comment: @ff524 Hmm... I suppose you either list universities or list mechanisms. The benefit of the latter is that there are fewer. The benefit of the former is that they're more easily distinguishable. For instance, several universities use mechanisms that are based on bidding but are substantially different from one another. In either case, the answer is not just "list-y," it's a list. I've started a [meta discussion](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2038/defining-shopping-questions) on whether that alone makes it a shopping question.

Comment: By the way, whether it's a list of mechanisms or institutions, I don't think it is a long one. I've been working on this question for some time, and I'm only aware of a handful of instances of programs using non-standard mechanisms for course assignment, though I have heard that they might be more prevalent outside of the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following institutions have (or had) non-standard course allocation mechanisms. Please add to this list if you know of others, or add additional links if you can find more detailed information on the various systems.

- New York University Law School (cannot find a link describing the system)
- Wharton ([Course Match](https://spike.wharton.upenn.edu/mbaprogram/course_match/), a bidding mechanism)
- MIT Sloan ([Sloan Course Bidding](https://sloanbid.mit.edu/registrar-student/Home.tap), a bidding mechanism)
- Harvard Business School ([Cross-registration](http://www.hbs.edu/mba/registrar/crossregistration/Pages/default.aspx), lottery based)
- Harvard Kennedy School ([Course registration](https://www.hks.harvard.edu/degrees/registrar/faculty/course-enroll), a bidding mechanism)

Other resources on course allocation mechanisms:

- [A blog post by Michael Law](https://blogs.law.harvard.edu/michaellaw/2013/09/14/course-bidding-is-auction-always-the-best/)